# Inverse kinematics ignore rotation constraints

Tags: armature, bones, constraints, inverse-kinematics

I applied rotation constraints to my bones so that they can only rotate around the X axis.

[image]

Then I use the "inverse kinematics" modifier and it completely ignores the rotation constraints.

[image]

How to force inverse kinematics to consider rotation constraints? Or maybe there is another way to limit the rotation of the bones so that it looks like a mechanical joint?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *Limit Rotation* constraint doesn't work on a bone that is part of the IK chain. To constrain the bone rotation, select it, go into the *Bone* panel > *Inverse Kinematics*, and lock or limit the rotation:

[image]